# Python OpenCV - Using cv2.UMat in separate thread leads to exit code -1

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, pycharm, opencl

I need to use cv2.UMat in a separate thread (continously read image data from a camera). My problem is that when using cv2.Umat in a separate Python thread, my application always exits with result -1.

The following Python programm is a very stripped down version of my problem but it's enough to reproduce the problem. How do I modify the following in order to let the programm exit without error (process result 0)?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import threading
import time

cv2_umat = None

def async_create_umat():
    np_mat = np.array([
        [[108, 108, 108], [108, 108, 108]],
        [[108, 108, 108], [108, 108, 108]],
        [[108, 108, 108], [108, 108, 108]]
    ])
    cv2_umat = cv2.UMat(np_mat) # Result is:  Process finished with exit code -1
    # cv2_umat = cv2.Mat(np_mat)  # Result is: Process finished with exit code 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    umat_thread = threading.Thread(target=async_create_umat)
    umat_thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    umat_thread.join()
```

I'm using Python 3.10.11. If installed the following packages:

```
alabaster==0.7.13
asttokens==2.4.1
atomicwrites==1.4.1
attrs==23.1.0
Babel==2.13.1
bracex==2.4
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
colorama==0.4.6
contourpy==1.1.1
cycler==0.12.1
decorator==5.1.1
deepdiff==5.2.3
docstring-inheritance==2.0.2
docutils==0.20.1
docx2pdf==0.1.8
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
exceptiongroup==1.1.3
executing==2.0.1
fonttools==4.43.1
idna==3.4
imagesize==1.4.1
iniconfig==2.0.0
ipython==8.17.2
jedi==0.19.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.5
llvmlite==0.39.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
matplotlib==3.8.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
numba==0.56.4
numpy==1.23.5
numpydoc==1.6.0
opencv-python==4.8.1.78
openpyxl==3.1.2
ordered-set==4.0.2
packaging==23.2
pandas==1.3.5
parse==1.19.1
parso==0.8.3
Pillow==10.1.0
plotly==5.6.0
pluggy==0.13.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.39
pure-eval==0.2.2
py==1.11.0
Pygments==2.16.1
pyparsing==3.1.1
pyserial==3.5
PySide6==6.5.2
PySide6-Addons==6.5.2
PySide6-Essentials==6.5.2
PySide6-QtAds==4.1.0.1
pytest==6.2.2
pytest-select==0.1.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
pywin32==306
requests==2.31.0
scipy==1.11.3
shiboken6==6.5.2
six==1.16.0
snowballstemmer==2.2.0
Sphinx==7.2.6
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.7
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.5
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.4
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.6
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.9
stack-data==0.6.3
tabulate==0.9.0
tenacity==8.2.3
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
tqdm==4.66.1
traitlets==5.13.0
urllib3==2.0.7
wcmatch==8.1.2
wcwidth==0.2.9
```

Comment: what OS are you on? I just pasted this into a `python -i` on Win10 and that finished without issues.

Comment: I´m on Windows 10. I've run that code from PyCharm 2023.2.3, 2022.1.4 and 2021.2.2. I'm using a virtual environment. The thread joins but the whole process newer finishes, thus I have to abort it.

Comment: try running it *outside of* PyCharm.